# Library no longer installs in Angular 14 projects

Tags: angular

I’m the author of the `ngx-disable-during-ajax` (`npm i ngx-disable-during-ajax`) library.

I made that library within Angular 13 and it worked within any Angular 13 projects. However since Angular 14 has come out any new Angular 14 projects fail to import my library.

I’ve seen this happen on a number of libraries not just mine. Did something big change in Angular 14? Does this mean I need to update my library to Angular 14?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that there's a mismatch between versions of **Angular** and **Angular CLI** or **Common** / **Schemantics**? I've had that problem and solved by:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm uninstall @angular/cli
npm cache clear --force
npm install @angular/cli@14.0.1
npm install -g @angular/cli@14.0.1
```

I'm just guessing so no hard feelings mate ✌

Comment: Thanks. I’d need to run this on my library?